# Javascript Cookie function

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have an question relating to my cookie function. Does it really have to have the $(function) for the if(readCookie) or can I specify just function like the rest of the code above it?
I've tried setting it a few different ways but without the $function it doesn't read the set cookie.
Can anybody help put me in the right direction. Thank you.

```
    <script>
    function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }`enter code here`
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    }

    function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
    }

    function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, "", -1);
    }

    $(function(){

    if(readCookie("style") == 'Dark'){
        $("body").removeClass().addClass("colour-scheme-1");         
        $(".styleswitch a").removeClass().addClass("Dark");
    }
    else {
    }

   });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's required. What that's doing is deferring execution of the code in that function until after the DOM has been completely built. If you didn't have that, then depending on exactly where on the page that script is imported it might not work at all.

If you were to move the whole `<script>` block to the very end of the `<body>`, it'd work without the jQuery "ready" setup.

Comment: I see, I currently have it in the <head> section, it's working but I've seen other websites that have it in the <head> and they haven't specified the $function just function.

Comment: @RossAnderson well it depends on what the code needs to do. The code inside your `$(...)` "ready" handler expects to be able to find the `<body>` tag and those `<a>` tags. If your code runs in the `<head>`, then without that the code would do nothing at all because at the time it runs the `<body>` hasn't been parsed yet by the browser.